# Scanf not reading first character

Tags: c, scanf

I have this, when I put the function in main the input is 'hello' and the output is 'ello'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getString() {
     char enter;
     printf("Type input below"); 
     scanf("%c", &enter);
     system("cls");
}

void scanString () {
     char target[100];
     scanf("%s", &target);
     printf("%s", target);
}

int main () {
     getString();
     scanString();
}
```

Comment: It's almost certainly because of something you did before calling `scanString()`, it read the first character. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I have tried it with and without the '&' in scanf, both produce the same issue. I have updated the post to include my full code.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. First you print "Type input below", then you read one character using `scanf("%c", &enter)`, then you clear the screen, then you read the rest of a word and print that in `scanString()`.

Comment: Small note: since you have `char target[100];` you probably want `scanf("%99s", target);`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getString` is explicitly eating a single character from `stdin` with `scanf("%c", &enter)` and ignoring it, so the second `scanf` in `scanString` doesn't receive that character. From the names used, it seems like you think you're consuming a newline the user already put in `stdin`, but in fact, the user is not entering a newline, they just enter `hello`, and you consume and discard the `h`, clear the screen, then consume and print the `ello`.

Comment: Consuming the newline is usually done *after* reading the desired input, not before.

Comment: @Barmar: I get the impression the intent was for it to consume the newline as a sort of virtual "Press Enter to Continue" prompt, then clear the screen, then receive the rest of the input on a clear screen. They just forgot to hit Enter before entering the "real" input (understandable, given the prompt gives them no reason to believe they need to hit Enter first).

Comment: That could be true, too. The name `getString()` is very strange for this, though.

Comment: @jacob87 Please mark the answer. This is the expected way to say "Thank you, this fixed my issue."

Answer (score 0):

If you omit

```
scanf("%c", &enter);
system("cls");
```

and correct your scanf statement for the string like below

```
scanf("%s", target); /* no need to use & with an array */
```

your code will work as you expect.

For more help, try my channel on YouTube, "Computing Foundations". I love helping beginners. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAZFaacJMNRm3JIn3nNR1cQ

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I reproduced the original problem and verified the fix. As the first commenter explained the problem correctly. I was helping the student along to a working version of their program.

Comment: After changing the misleading prose, you can now enhance your answer by some explanation, _why_ this corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getTarget () {
     char target[100];
     printf("Type input below and press ENTER");
     scanf("%99s", &target);
}
```

I moved the call to scanf to the same function where the user enters it so the variable is set when the user presses enter, not after.